# What operator/matrices can be written in Jordan normal form?

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

The wikipedia article is too bad in explaining. Is there any theorem that summarises which operators or matrices can be written in Jordan normal form?

Comment: If the matrices are over the field of complex numbers, then every square matrix is similar to one in Jordan canonical form. If the matrices are over the field of real numbers, then every matrix is similar to one in rational canonical form. For a general field, I don't know.

Comment: The Wikipedia page states conditions under which a matrix can be put into Jordan form: "If the vector space is over a field K, then a basis on which the matrix has the required form exists if and only if all eigenvalues of M lie in K, or equivalently if the characteristic polynomial of the operator splits into linear factors over K. This condition is always satisfied if K is the field of complex numbers."

Comment: That's too many words. Short and simple and less rigorous is fine with me.

Comment: In short, if you want to be able to put a matrix into Jordan form, then you need to be able to completely factor the characteristic polynomial into linear factors. This can't always be done if you're stuck with real numbers because sometimes the roots of the characteristic polynomial are complex, and you can't completely factor polynomials such as $x^{2}+1$ just using real numbers; that's why there's a "rational canonical form" for this case. Based on your remarks, I doubt that you care about the case of a general field $K$, but the same is true there, too.

Comment: I'm into physics hence the sloppyness. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score -1):

Every square matrix can be written in Jordan Canonical form. This asserts that every linear operator has a basis of generalized eigenvectors.

Comment: Is it the same with Schur decomposition?

Comment: Yes, every square matrix is similar to an upper triangular matrix.

Comment: It really depends a lot on the field.